# Pair of elements from a specified array whose sum equals a specific target number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am in mid of my JavaScript session. Find this code in my coding exercise. I understand the logic but I didn't get this map[nums[x]] condition.

```
function twoSum(nums, target_num) {  
    var map = [];  
    var indexnum = [];  

    for (var x = 0; x < nums.length; x++)  
    {  
        if (map[nums[x]] != null)  
        // what they meant by map[nums[x]]
        {  
            index = map[nums[x]];  
            indexnum[0] = index+1;  
            indexnum[1] = x+1;  
            break;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            map[target_num - nums[x]] = x;  
        }  
    }  
    return indexnum;  
    }  
console.log(twoSum([10,20,10,40,50,60,70],50));
```

I am trying to get the Pair of elements from a specified array whose sum equals a specific target number. I have written below code.

```
function arraypair(array,sum){
        for (i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
            var first = array[i];
            for (j = i + 1;j < array.length;j++) {
                var second = array[j];

                if ((first + second) == sum) {
            alert('First: ' + first + ' Second ' + second + ' SUM ' + sum);
            console.log('First: ' + first + ' Second ' + second);
                }
            }

        }
}

var a = [2, 4, 3, 5, 6, -2, 4, 7, 8, 9];

arraypair(a,7);
```

Is there any optimized way than above two solutions? Can some one explain the first solution what exactly map[nums[x]] this condition points to?

Comment: Say `y = num[x]`. What's the value of `y` ? Then what's the value of `map[y]` ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret While debugging the first solution, I am getting undefined twice and then 40. Totally confused about it

Comment: Both solutions returns expected results, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 yes..... But I dint understand 1st solution completely

Comment: If `map[nums[x]]` is does not equal `null`, set `map[target_num - nums[x]]` to `x`; else set `index` to  `map[nums[x]];`, `indexnum[0]` to `index+1;` , `indexnum[1]` to ` x+1; `

Comment: _rolleyes_ is was not helpful guest271314. I'd say that I'm an experienced developer but the intent of the first code is not intuitive at all and unclear to me on the first sight. And no matter if it's working it's bad code then. If the TO claims that it should find the pair that makes the passed sum, then his (2nd) code is clearer.

Comment: @try-catch-finally The first example finds the indexes within the passed array of the pairs whose sum equals number. The simplest approach would be to include `console.log()` in piece to review what each value is at each iteration

Comment: Although maybe clearer the second one suffers much worst complexity O(n*n) , while the first one is O(n), I suggest to take a deeper look at it ..it is pretty easy and not so unreadable. Definitely better than the second one!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

that **map** value you're seeing is a lookup table and that **twoSum** method has implemented what's called [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

In *Dynamic Programming*, you store values of your computations which you can re-use later on to find the solution.

### Lets investigate how it works to better understand it:

```
twoSum([10,20,40,50,60,70], 50)
//I removed one of the duplicate 10s to make the example simpler
```

#### In iteration 0:

value is 10. Our target number is 50. **When I see the number 10 in index 0, I make a note that if I ever find a 40 (50 - 10 = 40) in this list, then I can find its pair in index 0.**

So in our map, 40 points to 0.

#### In iteration 2:

value is 40. I look at map my map to see I previously found a pair for 40.

`map[nums[x]]` (which is the same as `map[40]`) will return 0.
**That means I have a pair for 40 at index 0.**
0 and 2 make a pair.

---

Does that make any sense now?

Unlike in your solution where you have 2 nested loops, you can store previously computed values. This will save you processing time, but waste more space in the memory (because the lookup table will be needing the memory)

Also since you're writing this in javascript, your **map** can be an object instead of an array. It'll also make debugging a lot easier ;)

Comment: was making sense even before... but someone had to write it down, good job!

Comment: @aec Will the first solution give entire pair of elements equal to the targeted sum??

Say for example this is my array elements twoSum([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70],50) will it return (0.50),(10,40),(20,30) ??

To my knowledge it will return only single pair set and stop execution

Comment: @PsycheGenie yes that is true. The function doesn't find all of the solutions. It returns the closest pair found.

Answer (score 20):

Using HashMap approach using time complexity approx O(n),below is the following code:

```
let twoSum = (array, sum) => {
    let hashMap = {},
      results = []

        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if (hashMap[array[i]]){
                results.push([hashMap[array[i]], array[i]])
            }else{
                hashMap[sum - array[i]] = array[i];
            }
          }
          return results;
    }
console.log(twoSum([10,20,10,40,50,60,70,30],50));
```

result:

```
{[10, 40],[20, 30]}
```

I think the code is self explanatory ,even if you want help to understand it,let me know.I will be happy enough to for its explanation.

Hope it helps..

Comment: I like this approach.  This line should be changed to handle when value is 0.  `if ( hashMap[array[i]] !== undefined ) {`, otherwise, the push to results doesn't happen.

Comment: Hi Prats, I'm just a newbie. can you explain under those loop and if-else statements?

Answer (score 5):

```
function twoSum(arr, S) {
 const sum = [];
  for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    for(let j = i+1;  j < arr.length; j++) {
      if(S == arr[i] + arr[j]) sum.push([arr[i],arr[j]])
    }
  }
 return sum
}
```

Brute Force not best way to solve but it works.

Comment: When I run this code it returns [NaN]

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below code. It will give you all the unique pairs whose sum will be equal to the targetSum. It performs the binary search so will be better in performance. The time complexity of this solution is O(NLogN)

```
((arr,targetSum) => {
    if ((arr && arr.length === 0) || targetSum === undefined) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (let x = 0; x <=arr.length -1; x++) {
            let partnerInPair = targetSum - arr[x];
            let start = x+1;
            let end = (arr.length) - 2;

             while(start <= end) {
                let mid = parseInt(((start + end)/2));
                if (arr[mid] === partnerInPair) {
                    console.log(`Pairs are ${arr[x]} and ${arr[mid]} `);
                    break;
                } else if(partnerInPair < arr[mid]) {
                    end = mid - 1;
                } else if(partnerInPair > arr[mid]) {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
             }
        };

    };
})([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 10)
```

Comment: Doesn't return 1,9 as a result.

Answer (score 3):

```
function twoSum(arr, target) {
    let res = [];
    let indexes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (target === arr[i] + arr[j] && !indexes.includes(i) && !indexes.includes(j)) {
                res.push([arr[i], arr[j]]);
                indexes.push(i);
                indexes.push(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
console.log('Result - ',
    twoSum([1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,10], 12)
);
```

Brute force.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const findTwoNum = ((arr, value) => {
let result = [];
for(let i= 0; i< arr.length-1; i++) {
    if(arr[i] > value) {
        continue;
    }
    if(arr.includes(value-arr[i])) {
        result.push(arr[i]);
        result.push(value-arr[i]);
        break;;
    }   
}
  return result;
});
let arr = [20,10,40,50,60,70,30];
const value = 120;
console.log(findTwoNum(arr, value));
```

OUTPUT :  Array [50, 70]

Answer (score 1):

Howaboutthis:

```
twoSum=(tra,lala)=>
  tra.reduce((ta,da,di)=>
    tra.indexOf(ba=lala-da)>di?ta.concat([[da,ba]]):ta,[]);
```

Use it like so:

```
console.log(twoSum([10, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70], 50));
```

If one wants multiple the same values in it, this can be done like so:

```
arrayUnique=tra=>[...new Set(tra)];

console.log(twoSum(arrayUnique([10, 20, 10, 40, 50, 60, 70]), 50));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function twoSum(arr){

  let constant = 17;

  for(let i=0;i<arr.length-2;i++){

      for(let j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){

          if(arr[i]+arr[j] === constant){

              console.log(arr[i],arr[j]);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myArr = [2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9];

function getPair(arr, targetNum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let cNum = arr[i]; //my current number
    for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (cNum !== arr[j] && cNum + arr[j] === targetNum) {
        let pair = {};
        pair.key1 = cNum;
        pair.key2 = arr[j];
        console.log(pair);
      }

    }
  }
}
getPair(myArr, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let  sumArray = (arr,target) => {
    let ar = []
    arr.forEach((element,index) => {
      console.log(index);      
      arr.forEach((element2, index2) => {
              if(  (index2 > index) && (element + element2 == target)){
                ar.push({element, element2})             
              }
          });
      });
      return ar
    }
    
      console.log(sumArray([8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1],10))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use {} hash object for storing and fast lookups.
2. Use simple `for` loop so you can return as soon as you find the right combo; array methods like `.forEach()` have to finish iterating no matter what.
3. And make sure you handle edges cases like this: `twoSum([1,2,3,4], 8)`---that should return `undefined`, but if you don't check for `!== i` (see below), you would erroneously return `[4,4]`. Think about why that is...

```
function twoSum(nums, target) {
  const lookup = {};
  
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    const n = nums[i];
    
    if (lookup[n] === undefined) {//lookup n; seen it before?
      lookup[n] = i; //no, so add to dictionary with index as value
    }
    
    //seen target - n before? if so, is it different than n?
    if (lookup[target - n] !== undefined && lookup[target - n] !== i) {
      return [target - n, n];//yep, so we return our answer!
    }  
  }
  
  return undefined;//didn't find anything, so return undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can fix this with simple JS object as well.

```js
const twoSum = (arr, num) => {
  let obj = {};
  let res = [];
  arr.map(item => {
    let com = num - item;
    if (obj[com]) {
      res.push([obj[com], item]);
    } else {
      obj[item] = item;
    }
  });
  return res;
};

console.log(twoSum([2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 9, 6, 8, 8, 7], 10));
// Output: [ [ 4, 6 ], [ 2, 8 ], [ 2, 8 ], [ 3, 7 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution In Java**

**Solution 1**

```
public static int[] twoNumberSum(int[] array, int targetSum) {        
          for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
           int first=array[i]; 
                   for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++){
                          int second=array[j];
                           if(first+second==targetSum){
                                 return new int[]{first,second};
                             }
                        }
            }
        return new int[0];
  }
```

**Solution 2**

```
public static int[] twoNumberSum(int[] array, int targetSum) {
     Set<Integer>  nums=new HashSet<Integer>();
         for(int num:array){
              int pmatch=targetSum-num;
               if(nums.contains(pmatch)){
                      return new int[]{pmatch,num};
                 }else{
                     nums.add(num);
                 }
             
         }
    return new int[0];
  }
```

**Solution 3**

```
public static int[] twoNumberSum(int[] array, int targetSum) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
         int left=0;
         int right=array.length-1;
         while(left<right){
             int currentSum=array[left]+array[right];
               if(currentSum==targetSum){
                      return new int[]{array[left],array[right]};
                 }else if(currentSum<targetSum){
                     left++;
                 }else if(currentSum>targetSum){
                     right--;
                 }
         }
    return new int[0];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findPairOfNumbers(arr, targetSum) {
    var low = 0, high = arr.length - 1, sum, result = [];
    while(low < high) {
        sum = arr[low] + arr[high];
        if(sum < targetSum)
            low++;
        else if(sum > targetSum)
            high--;
        else if(sum === targetSum) {
            result.push({val1: arr[low], val2: arr[high]});
            high--;
        }
    }  
    return (result || false);
}

var pairs = findPairOfNumbers([1,2,3,4,4,5], 8);
if(pairs.length) {
  console.log(pairs);
} else {
  console.log("No pair of numbers found that sums to " + 8);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple Solution would be in javascript is:

```
var arr = [7,5,10,-5,9,14,45,77,5,3];
var arrLen = arr.length;
var sum = 15;

function findSumOfArrayInGiven (arr, arrLen, sum){
  var left = 0;
  var right = arrLen - 1;

  // Sort Array in Ascending Order
  arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })

  // Iterate Over
  while(left < right){
    if(arr[left] + arr[right] === sum){
      return {
          res : true,
          matchNum: arr[left] + ' + ' + arr[right]
      };
    }else if(arr[left] + arr[right] < sum){
      left++;
    }else{
      right--;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

  var resp = findSumOfArrayInGiven (arr, arrLen, sum);

  // Display Desired output
  if(resp.res === true){
    console.log('Matching Numbers are: ' + resp.matchNum +' = '+ sum);
  }else{
    console.log('There are no matching numbers of given sum');
  }
```

Runtime test JSBin: https://jsbin.com/vuhitudebi/edit?js,console

Runtime test JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arbaazshaikh919/de0amjxt/4/

Answer (score -1):

```
function sumOfTwo(array, sumNumber) {
  for (i of array) {
    for (j of array) {
        if (i + j === sumNumber) {
            console.log([i, j])
        }
    }
  }
}
sumOfTwo([1, 2, 3], 4)
```

Comment: I had a similar question with some difference. I'm new at this. Hopefully it can help somehow. or you can show me a better way. Question was - Write a javascript function that takes an array of numbers and a target number. The function should find two different numbers in the array that, when added together, give the target number. For example: answer([1,2,3], 4)should return [1,3]

Answer (score -1):

```js
function twoSum(args , total) {
    let obj = [];
    let a = args.length;
    for(let i = 0 ; i < a ; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < a ; j++){
                if(args[i] + args[j] == total) {
                    obj.push([args[i] , args[j]])
                } 

        }
    }
    console.log(obj)}

twoSum([10,20,10,40,50,60,70,30],60);
/* */
```

Comment: Clearly your code produce wrong answer. `[30,30]` should not be a valid answer here. Also you consider `[10 50]` and `[50 10]` as separate answer, which is wrong as well. Besides, while sharing any code that solve any algorithmic problem, please try to explain the process and the expected complexity of your algorithm. Thanks.