# Expanding how this Two Sum algorithm works

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm currently practicing JS and came across this problem on Leetcode:

> Two Sum
>
> Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices
> of the two numbers such that they add up to the target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and
> you may not use the same element twice.
>
> You can return the answer in any order.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9 Output: [0,1] Output: Because
> nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: nums = [3,2,4], target = 6 Output: [1,2]
>
> Example 3:
>
> Input: nums = [3,3], target = 6 Output: [0,1]

I solved it with this:

```js
const twoSum = (nums, target) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
      if (nums[i] + nums[j] === target) return [i, j];
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

But then I checked the discussion for other solutions and stumbled upon this one:

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(let [k,v] of nums.entries()){
        if(nums.slice(k+1).lastIndexOf(target-v)>-1) return [k,nums.lastIndexOf(target-v)]}};
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/discuss/1543367/3-Lines-JavaScript-Two-Sum

I'm confused about how it's supposed to work especially on line 3. Tried console logging each step but ended up confusing myself even more.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: `k` is the index, `v` is the current number being iterated. slice the array at `k+1` so one index ahead of the current value, search for `target-v` (the compliment of the current value) in sliced array (everything ahead of the current value) starting from the end, if not `-1` (not found) the return `k`, the current index, and refind its compliment from the end. also see: [Pair of elements from a specified array whose sum equals a specific target number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967053/pair-of-elements-from-a-specified-array-whose-sum-equals-a-specific-target-numbe)

Comment: @pilchard Thank you for responding!

Just wondering how do the returned indices ([0, 1]) even verify that those are the elements we are looking for? It looked for the difference between the target and v but not the difference between the two elements.

Comment: `v` is one of the elements so `target - v` is the other element. (if `target = 9` and `v = 2`, then find the first `7` (`.lastIndexOf(9-2)`) in the remainder of the array.)

Comment: Awesome, that makes so much more sense now. Thank you so much!